# Hudson Continuous Integration configuration

Tags: hudson

I have set up Hudson but I am having difficulties, getting it to send mails, I have provided an smtp server (the gmail smtp server) but if I do tests, I get this error.

Failed to send out e-mail

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

I have seen some discussions on this in the forum when enabling tls through the command.

$ java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable="true" -jar hudson.war

How can you set tls to start if you are using hudson in tomcat? Is there some configuration file you can use?

Answer (score 4):

set your `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true` before starting your tomcat, if you're on unix you can just add

`JAVA_OPTS="-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"`

to your `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh` (somewhere at the top). On Windows I would set this in the cmdline-Environment.

Comment: Dosent work for me `JAVA_OPTS="-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true" java -jar /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/1.458/lib/jenkins.war`. Am not sure where is $TOMCAT_HOME on my mac :(

Comment: `java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable="true" -jar /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/1.458/lib/jenkins.war` worked :)